# Grouping doubles to map to create histogram

Tags: java, grouping, histogram

Let`s assume, that we have List of samples (type Double) {1.5, 1.1, 2.2, 1.0, 2.2, 3.3}. How can I achieve a Map that holds Integer as key (groups)  and number of occurrences as a Value of this Map?
For given example 1 -> 3, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 1. I know I can achieve this with if/else if or case logic but in my app it would be 30 different groups (30 cases or elseifs in code). 
App is creating wind histogram from given wind speed pulled from DB (millions of samples). 
My approach:

```
Map<Double, Long> map = windData.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(WindData::getSpeed, Collectors.counting()));
```

Where windData is list holding wind speeds, and getSpeed is retrieving wind speed value. This approach generates groups of doubles, which means that it only count occurrences and I would like to get 0-1, 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 etc. groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just round the `double` down to an `int` in the first parameter to `groupingBy`.  Your question first says that `List` of samples contains `Double`s but your code snippet suggests that it is actually a `List<WindData>`.  Which is it?

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
....

List<Double> speeds = ...;
Map<Integer, Long> histogram = speeds.stream()
               .collect(groupingBy(Double::intValue, counting()));
```

On a separate note, unless you are pulling this data from the database anyway for some other reason, consider doing this on the database side with SQL `group by`

Comment: WindData is a Class that holds wind data. For example wind speed, name of meteo station which measured wind speed etc. In this case getSpeed returns Double. My bad i should have mention that.

Comment: And what is the return type of `getSpeed`?

Comment: A Double value.

Comment: Then you should use `windspeed ->  windspeed.getSpeed().intValue()` as the first argument to `groupingBy`

Comment: When I try this solution it generates: Error:(33, 120) java: double cannot be dereferenced

Comment: It means that return type of `getSpeed` is not `Double` like you said but `double`.  Use `windspeed -> (int) windspeed.getSpeed()`.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank You! Can I ask one more question? Shall I change getSpeed return type to Double in my entity class?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pipeline producing "histogram" data from a stream of `double` values:

```
HashMap<Double, Long> res = 
        DoubleStream.of(1.5, 1.1, 2.2, 1.0, 2.2, 3.3)
        .collect(HashMap<Double, Long>::new,
                 (map, dbl) -> map.merge(Math.floor(dbl), 1L, (k, v) -> k + v), 
                 (map1, map2) -> map1.putAll(map2));
```

Printing `res` outputs `{2.0=2, 1.0=3, 3.0=1}`.

To apply this to your object stream, I'd just convert it to a double stream using `mapToDouble`:

```
windData.stream().mapToDouble(WindData::getSpeed)
    .collect(HashMap<Double, Long>::new,
                 (map, dbl) -> map.merge(Math.floor(dbl), 1L, (k, v) -> k + v), 
                 (map1, map2) -> map1.putAll(map2));
```

Note about the result: The keys of the map are the lower boundary of the interval (`0` is `0-1` and `1` is `1-2`)

Comment: Not sure why, but for my samples it generates Map with only two values in it. Keys  are working correctly.

Comment: @Jabbasnik I suspect `(k, v) -> v + 1` should rather be `(k, v) -> k + v`. Can't test at present, but it seems like a bug in my code, which explains why it shows 2 as value for key 1, when it should show 3.

Comment: After this change, this solution works as well as @Misha solution. Thank You!